# Contact Form 7 appears to use PHPMailer but somehow uses PHP mail().... How?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, phpmailer

Issue: I'm attempting to send mail from a contact form created using the Contact Form 7 (CF7) plugin for Wordpress. I've configured the basic form, sending to my personal email upon success. However, each submission results in a failure.

Environment: Docker wordpress container (runs only Apache, no sendmail program installed). Also, in wp-config.php, I've added this block to configure PHPMailer to use IsSMTP, and this has tested successful in all other places in WP, as well as with manual PHP scripts:

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'phpmailer' );
function phpmailer( $phpmailer ) {
        $phpmailer->isSMTP();
        $phpmailer->Host = 'mysmtpopenrelayserver';
        $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = false;
}
```

Expectation: Upon inspection of Contact Form 7 plugin file /includes/mail.php, it should be using phpmailer(), but the Apache error log shows an email of "sh: sendmail: command not found" so this indicates to me that CF7 is really attempting to use mail() function instead.

I need some explanation to better understand what's going on here. I don't want to install sendmail into this container.

Comment: Should've mentioned this. In wp-config.php, I've set the phpmailer to use IsSMTP and provided it with our open SMTP relay server. It works! I get all emails from WP core. But CF7 still attempts to use IsMail. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default PHPMailer (and thus CF7, I assume) acts as a big wrapper around PHP's built-in `mail()` function. The `mail` function requires that you have a working local mail server, most commonly postfix.

To work around this, configure CF7 to ask PHPMailer to use its own SMTP client, which will then send directly via whatever relay you configure (e.g. gmail), will not call `mail` and thus does not require a local mail server.

Comment: I specified in wp-config.php to use phpmail->IsSMTP; I know this works because I don't have sendmail on the server and emails send from phpmailer just fine. When I create a new users in WP, I get an email. If I write a php script to send mail using phpmailer, I get it. 'add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'mail_relay' );
function mail_relay( \$phpmailer ) {
        $phpmailer->isSMTP();
        $phpmailer->Host = 'oursmtprelayserver';
        $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = false;'

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like CF7 is bypassing or undoing your settings. If you set a breakpoint you should be able to catch it in the act.

Answer (score 0):

[`wp_mail()` calls `PHPMailer::IsMail()` internally](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L413) (see [the PHPMailer docs](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=methods)).

This ensures that PHPMailer uses PHP's built-in `mail()` function.